# Flot: Different Colors in chart plot area of flot chart

Tags: flot

Ahoy,

I have a flot chart on which I was able to get different colors on the plot area using the following

```
 grid   : { borderWidth:0,markings:[
               {yaxis: { from: 200.0, to: 240.0 },color: "rgba(0,255,0,0.3)"},

       {yaxis: { from: 100.0, to: 120.0 },color: "rgba(255,0,0,0.3)"},
       {yaxis: { from: 120.0, to: 180.0 },color: "rgba(255,255,0,0.3)"},
       {yaxis: { from: 260.0, to: 360.0 },color: "rgba(255,255,0,0.3)"},
           {yaxis: { from: 360.0, to: 460.0 },color: "rgba(255,0,0,0.3)"}
                        ]}
                };
```

But I am getting solid colrs. What I need is something in the image given below [Blending of colors]. 
[image]

How would I attain it ?

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the grid backgroundColor option, which allows you to specify a gradient.  The [Specifying Gradients](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#specifying-gradients) section of the docs has more info and examples.

To synchronize the colors with the y-axis ticks is a little more difficult; you'll need to know in advance how many ticks there are, or guarantee it via the yaxis 'ticks' option.  You can then edit the gradient spec to add color entries for each tick, i.e. if there is just one tick, you would have an array with three colors: one for the top, one at tick #1, and one for the bottom of the grid.

Comment: but how would I add different gradient colors on the basis of successive y-axis ticks

Comment: would Grid: { markings: [yaxis: { from: 200.0, to: 240.0 },colors: [color1, color2, color3]}, so on } work? Do u have any working example in JSFiddle? I am travelling right now so couldn't try first hand

Comment: Markings don't support gradients; see my update to the answer.

Comment: Yes., there are a total of 5 ticks namely 55, 110, 220, 440 and 880.

Comment: Plz upvote my question if you think this would help others as well who are looking for exact/similar answer